Widget con dos callbacks enlazadas al mismo evento ¿Cómo seguir ejecutando la segunda a pesar de que la primera ejecute un "break"?
Tengo un widget entry de tkinter que tiene dos eventos enlazados:
TXhoras.bind("<Key>", lambda event: calculo_horas.calcula_horas(event,TXhn,TXhe,TVtabla,CBnombres,SB), add="+")
TXhoras.bind("<Key>", validacion.valida_horas)

Los dos eventos se refieren al mismo tipo de evento, que es pulsar una tecla.
El primer evento lo que hace es que solo deja poner números en el widget, todo lo que no sea número usa break para que el evento de clase no lo ponga en el widget.
El problema es que el segundo evento no se ejecuta cuando en el primer evento ejecuta un break y necesito que se ejecute el segundo evento. ¿Cómo podría resolverlo?
El código del primer evento es:
def valida_horas(event):
    if event.keysym in ("Home","End","Left","Right","BackSpace", "Delete"):
            return
        if event.widget.select_present():
            event.widget.delete(event.widget.index(ctk.SEL_FIRST), event.widget.index(ctk.SEL_LAST))
        if event.widget.index(ctk.INSERT) == 4:
            event.widget.delete(4, "end")
            return "break"
        if event.widget.index(ctk.INSERT) == 0:
            if event.char in "0123456789":
                event.widget.insert(0, event.char)
                return "break"
            else:
                return "break" 
        if event.widget.index(ctk.INSERT) == 1 and event.widget.get()[0] == "0" and event.char in "0123456789": 
            return "break"
        
        if event.widget.index(ctk.INSERT) == 1 and event.char in "0123456789.":
            if  event.widget.get()[0] == "0" and event.char == ".":
                event.widget.insert(1, event.char)
                return "break"
            if event.char != ".":
                if int(event.widget.get()[0] + event.char) > 12:
                    event.widget.delete(1, ctk.END)
                    return "break"
                else:
                    event.widget.insert(1, event.char)
                    return "break"
            else:
                event.widget.insert(1, event.char)
                return "break"
        
        if event.widget.index(ctk.INSERT) == 1:
            return "break"
        
        if event.widget.index(ctk.INSERT) == 2 and event.widget.get()[1] == ".": 
            if event.char in "0123456789":
                event.widget.insert(2, event.char)
                return "break"
            else:
                return "break"
            
        if event.widget.index(ctk.INSERT) == 2:
            return "break"
        
        if event.widget.index(ctk.INSERT) == 3 and event.widget.get()[1] == ".": 
            if event.char in "0123456789":
                event.widget.insert(3, event.char)
                return "break"
            else:
                return "break"

y el código del segundo evento es:
hn = event.widget.get() + event.char
hn = float(hn)
he = int(event.char)
i = -1
    while TVtabla.set(TVtabla.get_children()[i], "Nombre") == CBnombres.get() and TVtabla.set(TVtabla.get_children()[i], "Fecha") == SB.get():
        if TVtabla.set(TVtabla.get_children()[i], "Thoras") == "801" or TVtabla.set(TVtabla.get_children()[i], "Thoras") == "809":
            he = he + int(TVtabla.set(TVtabla.get_children()[i], "Horas"))
        else:
            hn = hn + int(TVtabla.set(TVtabla.get_children()[i], "Horas"))
        i = i - 1
    TXhn.delete(0, ctk.END)
    TXhe.delete(0, ctk.END)
    TXhn.insert(0, str(hn))
    TXhe.insert(0, str(he))

Éste segundo evento calcula un sumatorio de horas que hay en TVtabla (un witget treeview) en tiempo real.

Cuando la callback asociada a un evento retorna "break" la propagación del mismo se detiene en ese punto, ninguna otra callback  que le suceda en la cola correspondiente a ese vento será ejecutada.
Dicho esto, si quieres que se ejecute la segunda función siempre que se produce el evento, independientemente de lo que la primera retorne, una forma simple de sonseguirlo sin modificar tus funciones es crear un wrapper que llame a ambas, enlazarlo al evento a el solo y que retorne el retorno de la primera función.
Un ejemplo muy simple, la primera callback valida que solo se ingresen números y retorna "break" si el carácter no lo es:
import tkinter as tk    

root = tk.Tk()
entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

def first_handler(event):
    print("First handler")
    if event.char not in "0123456789":
        print("Break")
        return "break"
    
def second_handler(event):
    print("Second handler")

def handler_wrapper(event):
    handler_return = first_handler(event)
    second_handler(event)
    return handler_return
    
entry.bind("<Key>", handler_wrapper)

root.mainloop()

Si te es necesario, puedes modificar el evento de acuerdo al retorno de la primera callback, por ejemplo, ésto elimina el carácter ingresado si la primera callback no lo valida:
def handler_wrapper(event):    
    handler_return = first_handler(event)
    if handler_return == "break":
        event.char = ""
    second_handler(event)
    return handler_return


Una aclaración, add="+" se debe usar al enlazar las callbacks sucesivas, no en la primera llamada a bind. CustomTkinter (que parece que usas) tiene el argumento add con valor "+" por defecto, por lo que esto es irrelevante, pero no en tkinter vanilla, dónde:
entry.bind("<Key>", first_handler, add='+')
entry.bind("<Key>", second_handler)

hará que solo second_handler sea llamada, debe ser:
entry.bind("<Key>", first_handler)
entry.bind("<Key>", second_handler, add='+')

y en este orden.
